# Installing Google Analytics on a Website with No Includes

Tags: php, google-analytics, include, php-include

I have been tasked with installing Google Analytics on a website for a client.

Unfortunately, this website was put together by people with very little knowledge in PHP.

The only common file included throughout the site is the configuration file, which is only used to connect to the database. This file is executed before even the opening HTML tag.

The website itself doesn't have an official header. Some pages have their own custom navigation bar.

If I placed the Google Analytics code in the configuration file (which takes place before any HTML), there's a good chance that modern internet browsers will be able to figure out what to do with it, but it's a dirty solution that I feel could be prone to having problems down the road.

I'm asking this question with a reasonable doubt that there is any easy solution to get this done, but I'm still at the stage in my web dev career in which I'm learning new things everyday, and it wouldn't surprise me if there's an easy way out.

Thanks.

If I'm missing any details, please let me know and I'll do my best to include any other relevant information.

Comment: Unfortunately, if the site isn't structured at all and isn't using templates or anything, you don't have much of a choice other than refactor to do this right.  The good news is, refactoring can only help and if you do it now you'll save yourself a ton of time in the long run.  These sorts of sites tend to have a lot of inconsistencies... you'll probably fix 50 bugs just by spending an hour cleaning things up.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was afraid that that might be the case here. I will see what the client wants to do about this.

Comment: Manage your client's expectations.  If your client has made it this far with such a broken site, they will undoubtedly ask you to hack around it, since they often won't know the difference.  It's never fun to be the tech delivering bad news to a new client, and the client is always suspicious.  Explain it as clearly and as accurately as possible, and make the right suggestion.  In the end, if your client wants you to keep working around serious problems, it might be best to get new clients.  Been there, done that... the clients that take most of your time always pay the least.

Comment: Just spoke to the client and they are on board for getting this fixed the right way. I'm sure this will pay off for them in the long run. I appreciate your help. :) (And +1 for Chicagoland web developers)

Comment: Awesome!  Keep that client around, they are rare.